# How is it ensured that a CNN does not learn the same filter multiple times?

Tags: neural-networks, conv-neural-network, convolution

Let's say we have a dataset of pictures displaying straight vertical lines with different translations or nothing (just an example), and we apply a CNN to that. We choose that the CNN should learn N filters. By construction of our problem, we know that the CNN would just need a single filter to succeed at the prediction line / no line. Yet, we are forcing it to learn N filters. Will it learn N times the same filter with the vertical line (maybe with slightly different numerical values)? Or is there some mechanism that will ensure the diversity of filters? In that case, the one of the N filters that has best learned the vertical line, will probably have the strongest connection in the fully connected layer to the output, right?

Thanks!